# Values disappear after save in Odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I am working on odoo 10.On onchange I need to set the `purchase_order_line` values in `move_lines` field on `stock_picking`. It will set the values to the field, but after I save the record move_lines field is empty(values disappeared).

My Code:

```
data = {
    'name': line.product_id.name,
    'price_unit': line.price_unit,
    'product_uom': line.product_uom.id,
    'product_uom_qty': line.product_qty,
    'purchase_line_id': line.id,
    'procurement_id': line.procurement_ids.id,
    'date_expected': date_planned,
    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
    'state': 'draft',
    'origin': line.order_id.name,
    'location_id': line.product_id.property_stock_production.id,
    'picking_id': self.id,
    'location_dest_id': line.order_id.picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id.id
}
move = self.env['stock.move'].create(data)
self.move_lines = move
```

It will set the line values to the `move_lines` field.But after it is not appear in the field.

I don't know where I done the mistake?!

Comment: Hint: your priorities are not ours. Orders like: ASAP will only help collecting you downvotes. ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

move_lines fields it's a one2many or many2many. Odoo is waiting for a **tuple**

**(0, 0, { values })** link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary

**(1, ID, { values })** update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)

**(2, ID)** remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)

**(3, ID)** cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)

**(4, ID)** link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)

**(5)** unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)

**(6, 0, [IDs])** replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)